# The order of executing triggers on bulk inserts

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert, database-trigger

Assume we are inserting 1000 (from 1 to 1000) rows in one statement into one table.

The table has one before and one after trigger.

What the order of processing of these rows?

At this moment I suppose:

1. Before trigger execution for 1st row
2. insert the 1st row
3. Before trigger execution for 2nd row
4. insert the 2nd row
   ......

Then at the end the after triggers will be called in an undefined order.

Am I right? Where can I find the proofs of my assumptions?

Comment: Are those triggers row level triggers or statement level triggers?

Answer (score 1):

It depends your after insert trigger is row-level triggers or statement-level triggers.
Statement triggers are triggered once after each statement

`...
FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE xyz();`

And if you want the trigger to execute for each affected row and that means you want a row-level trigger.

`...
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE xyz();`